# Minimum Samples Per Chip?

Tags: digital-communications, correlation, nyquist

Is there a 'Nyquist Criteria' for the minimum samples per chip that are needed for a correlator? I've heard 2, but will 1 work? What are the implications of having less than the minimum (in the context of radar and communications)?

Comment: What exactly is this *samples per chip* quantity you're taking about? What is a *chip*?

Comment: @Phonon I believe that he is referring to DSSS chips.

Answer (score 1):

Actually much less than 1 sample/chip will work for DSSS. Doing so erodes the spreading gain and makes *chip* level detection impractical, but it works. The undersampled spreading sequence simply acts as a vector (subspace) for the undersampled signal.  Matched filtering is still matched filtering -- as long as you are still sampled well above the *symbol* (not chip) rate.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to do 1 sample/chip because if you happen to have the samples at the chip transitions then demodulation will go poorly.  Also, if you have much carrier offset you will likely lose and/or alias part of the signal.